# Why does this alignment not work with this "cases" environment?

Tags: vertical-alignment, cases

I'm trying to align a short equation and a long one.

[image]

Could you explain why the highlighted parts are not properly aligned?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
d x_t^i &= v_t^i d t, \\
\begin{split}
d v_t^i &= - (\nabla U (X_t^{i, n}) - \nabla U (\bar X_t^i)) d t \\
& \qquad + \bigg [ \bigg ( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n K (X_t^{i, n} - X_t^{j, n}) \bigg )^m - (K* \mu_t)^m (\bar X_t^i) \bigg ] d B_t^i. 
\end{split}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have a two row aligment the second row has no `&` just a nested split on the left hand side and an empty right hand side so the right edge of the split aligns with right edge of dx_t^i above. remove the `split` so all three rows in one `aligned`

Comment: `Package amsmath Warning: Cannot use 'split' here; trying to recover with 'aligned' on input line 12.` Shouldn't it be alright if you don't use the `split` environment? Also I'd align the equations *after* the `=`, i.e. `... ={}& ...`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In that way, I could not label the whole long equation...

Comment: you have no labels anyway. `\[` is unnumbred, and `aligned` and `split`  do not make labeled rows, just subterms like `array`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole line will get a single equation number (if you decide to have it numbered), so I personally don't see any (too important) reason why you should use `split` here. You should get the desired output by the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        d x_t^i ={}& v_t^i d t, \\
        d v_t^i ={}& - (\nabla U (X_t^{i, n}) - \nabla U (\bar X_t^i)) d t \\
        & + \biggl [ \biggl ( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n K (X_t^{i, n} - X_t^{j, n}) \biggr )^m - (K* \mu_t)^m (\bar X_t^i) \biggr ] d B_t^i.
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

I deliberately changed the position of alignment to be *after* the equal sign, such that `-` and `+` are aligned.

Personally I'd also like to have the exponent after the `biggr` parenthesis to be closer to the parenthesis, so I'd prefer `\biggr)^{\mkern-3mu m}` or similar.

Comment: In thaisway, I could not label the whole long equation...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you can't label the second equation individually. If you replace `\[...\]` by `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` the whole thing will get a single label

Comment: Please, use `\biggl` and `\biggr`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `IEEEeqnarraybox` environment from the [`IEEEtrantools`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetrantools) package. Its usage is somewhat like tabular environment. [Here](https://moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf) is a helpful documentation of the environment.

[image: o/p]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\{
\begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}[][c]{rCl}
    d x_t^i &=& v_t^i d t, \\
    d v_t^i &=& - (\nabla U (X_t^{i, n}) - \nabla U (\bar X_t^i)) d t \\
            & & \negmedspace{} + \bigg [ \bigg ( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n K (X_t^{i, n} - X_t^{j, n}) \bigg )^m - (K* \mu_t)^m (\bar X_t^i) \bigg ] d B_t^i.\\
\end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `{}` before `+`, but not before `-` in the line above? Anyway, +1.

Comment: @Οὖτις Otherwise, `+` is treated as a unary operator and the spacing is not consistent. Btw, should have used a `\negmedspace` to align the `+` with `-` correctly.

Answer (score 4):

`split` can only be used at the top level of `equation` or `align` (in the latter case only one alignment point in the outer `align` is allowed).

Using `split` inside `aligned` is an error and LaTeX tells you.

Just use a single `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
dx_t^i &= v_t^i \,dt, \\
dv_t^i &= - (\nabla U (X_t^{i, n}) - \nabla U (\bar X_t^i)) \,dt \\
       &\hphantom{={}}+
        \biggl[
          \biggl(
            \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n K (X_t^{i, n} - X_t^{j, n})
          \biggr)^{\!m}
          - (K* \mu_t)^m (\bar X_t^i)
        \biggr] \,dB_t^i.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that you should use `\biggl` for opening and `\biggr` for closing delimiters. Also, differentials should be preceded by `\,` if there's something before them.

It's better if you add `\!` in the exponent to a `\biggr)`, so there's less space between them.

With `\hphantom{={}}` we get the exact space of the = sign in the upper line.

[image]